# Centralize row label in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table and it is fine, but I would like to centralize one of the row labels.

I tried to use `\centralizing` before `\multirow`, `\begin{center}Integration\end{center}` and `\vspace` and `\hspace` (since it is inside `\begin{sideways}` INTEGRATION `\end{sideways}` what gave me 0 results.

Here is the table code and afterward a picture highlighting the label I want to centralize.

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\cmidrule{5-10}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2016} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2017} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2018} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Set} & Item  & Description & $\alpha$    & M     & (SD)  & M     & (SD)  & M     & (SD) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}YYYYYYYYYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ16 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.  & 0.89  & 4     & 0.44  & 4     & 0.67  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ17 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.91  & 4     & 0.68  & NA    & NA    & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ18 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.88  & 4     & 0.67  & 4     & 0.76  & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ19 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.86  & NA    & NA    & NA    & NA    & 3     & (NA) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\begin{sideways}YYYYYYYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ20 & \multicolumn{1}{p{29.1em}|}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\newline{}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \newline{}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. } & 0.88  & 4     & 0.45  & 4     & 0.71  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ21 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.88  & 4     & 0.57  & 4     & 0.73  & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ22 & \multicolumn{1}{p{29.1em}|}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.} & 0.93  & 4     & 0.56  & 5     & 0.71  & 2     & (NA) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}YYYYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ26 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.86  & 4     & 0.61  & 4     & 0.62  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ27 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.89  & 4     & 0.68  & NA    &       & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ28 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.85  & 4     & 0.68  & 4     & 0.79  & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ29 & \multicolumn{1}{p{29.1em}|}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \newline{}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.} & 0.85  & 4     & 0.58  & 4     & 0.64  & 3     & (NA) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}YYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ32 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.93  & 4     & 0.91  & NA    & NA    & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ33 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.88  & 3     & 1.13  & NA    & NA    & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ34 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.92  & NA    & NA    & NA    & NA    & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ35 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.89  & 4     & 1.02  & NA    & NA    & 3     & (NA) \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
```

[image]

Comment: What you mean with centralized row? Do you like to have one more column with some text on vertical center of table? For testing your table code please extend it to complete small document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: I suppose `YYYYYYYYYYYYY` is some sot of placeholder. In your actual table, is there just a single quite long word or are there several shorter words in this cell? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but horizontal lines from `booktabs` are not intended to be sed in cmbination with vertical lines hence the small "gaps"  in the vertical lines around the interceptions. If you wish to keep that many lines in your table, you might want to use regular `\hline` and `\cline` commands in combination with the `cellspace` package.

Comment: \multirow{4}{*}[-1.2ex]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{YYYYYY}} --- the text has been shortened otherwise overflows to next row

Comment: @leandriis it is just one word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table has many issues:

- extremely long unnatural word, which can't be hyphenated  (in MWE below I interrupt them with inter word spaces that can be hyphenated).
- in table you define very long `cells`, which case a lot empty space in third column
- using horizontal rules from `booktabs` are not intended for use of the vertical lines
- rotated text is much longer than available lenght in `multirow` cell. You should consider to write this text in more lines
- you not provide any information about your document layout nor if table can be in the landscape orientation

Anyway, I guessing, that the following table may be what you looking for:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cellspace, multirow, tabularx}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{L}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|l|S{L}|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \cline{5-10}    
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2016} 
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2017}
                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2018} \\
    \hline
   {Set} & Item  & Description & $\alpha$ & M & (SD) & M & (SD)  & M & (SD) \\
    \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{sideways}\parbox{6em}{\centering AAA AAAA AAA AAA}\end{sideways}} 
    & postQ16 & xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx.  & 0.89  & 4     & 0.44  & 4     & 0.67  & 0     & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ17 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx. & 0.91  & 4     & 0.68  & NA    & NA    & 1     & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ18 & xxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx. & 0.88  & 4     & 0.67  & 4     & 0.76  & 2     & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ19 & xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx. & 0.86  & NA    & NA    & NA    & NA    & 3     & (NA) \\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}\parbox{6em}{\centering BBB BBBBB BBB}\end{sideways}} 
    & postQ20 & {xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx. } & 0.88  & 4     & 0.45  & 4     & 0.71 & 0     & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ21 & xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx. & 0.88 & 4 & 0.57 & 4  & 0.73  & 1 & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ22 & {xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx.} & 0.93 & 4 & 0.56 & 5 & 0.71  & 2 & (NA) \\
    \hline
    \multirow{6}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}CCCCCCCC\end{sideways}} 
    & postQ26 & xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx. & 0.86 & 4 & 0.61 & 4  & 0.62  & 0  & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ27 & xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxx. & 0.89 & 4 & 0.68  & NA &   & 1 & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}         
    & postQ28 & xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx. & 0.85  & 4 & 0.68  & 4 & 0.79  & 2 & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}         
    & postQ29 & {xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx.} 
        & 0.85  & 4  & 0.58  & 4 & 0.64 & 3  & (NA) \\
    \hline
    \multirow{8}{*}{\begin{sideways}DDDDDD\end{sideways}} 
    & postQ32 & xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx. & 0.93  & 4 & 0.91 & NA & NA & 0     & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ33 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx. 
        & 0.88  & 3 & 1.13 & NA & NA & 1 & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ34 & xxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx. 
        & 0.92  & NA    & NA    & NA    & NA    & 2     & (NA) \\
    \cline{2-10}          
    & postQ35 & xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx. 
        & 0.89  & 4     & 1.02  & NA    & NA    & 3     & (NA) \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that the YYYY-labels have to many characters, they overflow the available space. You will see the problem if you shorten them. You have several options: Shorten the text, reduce the font size, use multiple lines.

I have change the the tabular to simplify the code. First, the seven rightmost column should be of the same width. I use seven fixed width `w`-columns using [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array)-package. Also, I changed the tabular to be a [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and set the third column as an `X`-column where tabularx calculate the correct width. Since X-columns are paragraph columns, you can remove the `\multirow` several places. In addition, I removed the vertical lines.

If your sideways heading are long and you need more than one rows for the heading, I have added a second example, which do that. I define a macro `\swthead` that have two arguments, the first is the distance you want hte heading to move up to be centred, the other argument is the heading itself. The macro puts a table in a `rotatebox`, which also means that you have to break the lines yourself using `\\`. As I said, you alignment the heading by adding a distance in `pt` as first parameter in the macro.

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, rotating, pdflscape, multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cl>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{7}{wr{0.75cm}}@{}}
\cmidrule{5-10}    \multicolumn{4}{r}{}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2016} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2017} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{2018} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Set} & Item  & Description & $\alpha$    & M     & (SD)  & M     & (SD)  & M     & (SD) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering\small YYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ16 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.  & 0.89  & 4     & 0.44  & 4     & 0.67  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ17 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.91  & 4     & 0.68  & NA    & NA    & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ18 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.88  & 4     & 0.67  & 4     & 0.76  & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ19 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.86  & NA    & NA    & NA    & NA    & 3     & (NA) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3.5}[6]{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering\small YYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ20 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.88  & 4     & 0.45  & 4     & 0.71  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ21 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.88  & 4     & 0.57  & 4     & 0.73  & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ22 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.93  & 4     & 0.56  & 5     & 0.71  & 2     & (NA) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4.25}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering\small YYYYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ26 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.86  & 4     & 0.61  & 4     & 0.62  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ27 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.89  & 4     & 0.68  & NA    &       & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ28 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.85  & 4     & 0.68  & 4     & 0.79  & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ29 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.85  & 4     & 0.58  & 4     & 0.64  & 3     & (NA) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3.5}[8]{*}{\begin{sideways}\centering\small YYYYYY\end{sideways}} & postQ32 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.93  & 4     & 0.91  & NA    & NA    & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ33 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.88  & 3     & 1.13  & NA    & NA    & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ34 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.92  & NA    & NA    & NA    & NA    & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & postQ35 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.89  & 4     & 1.02  & NA    & NA    & 3     & (NA) \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, rotating, pdflscape, multirow, tabularx}

\newcommand*{\swthead}[2]{%
\raisebox{#1}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\small\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{c} #2\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup%
}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ll>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{7}{wr{0.75cm}}@{}}
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){5-10}
\multicolumn{4}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2016} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{2017} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{2018} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Set} & Item  & Description & $\alpha$ &
 M & (SD) & M & (SD) & M & (SD)\\
\midrule
  & postQ16 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.89 & 4 & 0.44  & 4     & 0.67  & 0     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
  & postQ17 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.91 & 4 & 0.68  & NA    & NA    & 1     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
  & postQ18 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.88 & 4 & 0.67  & 4     & 0.76  & 2     & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
\swthead{25pt}{YYYYYYYY\\ZZZ} & postQ19 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.86 & NA & NA & NA & NA & 3 & (NA) \\
\midrule
  & postQ20 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.88 & 4 & 0.45 & 4 & 0.71  & 0 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
  & postQ21 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.88 & 4 & 0.57 & 4 & 0.73 & 1 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
\swthead{22pt}{YYYYYYYY} & postQ22 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.93 & 4 & 0.56 & 5 & 0.71 & 2 & (NA) \\
\midrule
  & postQ26 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.86 & 4 & 0.61 & 4 & 0.62 & 0 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10} 
  & postQ27 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.89 & 4 & 0.68 & NA & & 1 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10} 
  & postQ28 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.85 & 4 & 0.68  & 4 & 0.79 & 2 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
\swthead{20pt}{YYYYYYYY}  & postQ29 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.85 & 4 & 0.58  & 4 & 0.64  & 3 & (NA) \\
\midrule
  & postQ32 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.93 & 4 & 0.91 & NA & NA & 0 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
  & postQ33 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.88 & 3 & 1.13 & NA & NA & 1 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
  & postQ34 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 0.92 & NA & NA & NA & NA & 2 & (NA) \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-10}
\swthead{25pt}{YYYYYYYY} & postQ35 & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. & 0.89 & 4 & 1.02 & NA & NA    & 3 & (NA) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```